# I can't find this website when I perform a Google search for its name

Tags: seo, google-search

I have this website: https://www.rocheeolas.ie/en_ie.html
When I'm trying to do a Google search by using the title of the page then, the search result does not show up. 
You can see the robots file here: https://www.rocheeolas.ie/content/hcp-portals/hcp-portal-next-ireland.robots.txt

And the sitemap is here: https://www.rocheeolas.ie/content/hcp-portals/hcp-portal-next-ireland.sitemap.xml

I have another similar site (https://www.rochegate.fi/fi_fi.html), and this isn't showing up as a Google search result if I search by the title "Roche Gate."

What do I need to look up to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner of this website you can submit it to the Google index so that the Google bots can get to your website quicker to be added as a search result. Here is the link to submit it to the Google index:

www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url/